# Restarting after installing Cyanogenmod, it is just going around

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-optimus-2x

I installed cyanogenmod 10.1, following the steps of [this link](http://www.knowtechbetter.net/how-to-install-android-4-2-2-jelly-bean-on-lg-optimus-2x-p990-with-cm10-1-custom-rom/). After the restart, it only shows the logo going around. It did not change in the last 5 hours.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has happened to me also. Do a full wipe and flash the ROM again. It takes around 5-10 mins for first boot.

Comment: what is a full wipe?

Comment: In ClockWorkMod Select the Wipe Factory/Data Reset.Before doing this Do a Nandroid Backup.If anything wrong happens u can Restore it.